# Implement tab completion

Tags: code-golf, string

[Tab completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion) is a useful feature that auto-completes partially written commands.  You're going to be implementing it.

For example, if the available commands were `['apply','apple','apple pie','eat']`, then `a` would complete to  `appl`, as all of the commands that start with `a` also start with `appl`.

## Input/Output

You need to input a string, A, and a set of strings, B.

You need to output the longest common prefix of all B that starts with A.

- If none of the options starts with A, then return A
- You can assume that B is nonempty, and that all strings are nonempty
- You cannot assume that any of the options start with A, nor that the common prefix will be longer than A
- You can be case sensitive or case insensitive.
- You only need to handle printable ASCII
- Built-ins that explicitly do this task are allowed

## Test cases:

```
'a'       ['apply','apple','apple pie','eat'] => 'appl'
'a'       ['apple pie']                       => 'apple pie'
'apple'   ['eat','dine']                      => 'apple'
'program' ['programa','programb']             => 'program'
'*%a('    ['*%a()-T>','*%a()-T<','@Da^n&']    => '*%a()-T'
'a'       ['abs','absolute','answer']         => 'a'
'a'       ['a','abs']                         => 'a'
'one to'  ['one to one','one to many']        => 'one to '
```

Note the trailing space on the last test case

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so make your answers as short as possible!

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/78094/34531)

Comment: Could you add an example with non-alphabetic, printable ASCII characters for posterity?

Comment: More examples with non-alphabetic characters couldn't hurt. I just deleted my answer because I realized that it broke with inputs containing `\​` or `'`.

Comment: Not sure how to represent `'` in an example.  If I use `"` for the strings, then the strings are different than other examples.

Comment: That's *exactly* the problem my answer had. :P

Comment: What is the result for `'a'` and `['a','abs']?

Comment: Good test case! `'a'`

Comment: Do we have to deal with an empty command list?

Comment: @Titus nope. "You can assume that B is nonempty, and that all strings are nonempty"

Comment: May we assume B has no trailing spaces?

Answer (score 10):

### JavaScript (ES6), 75 bytes

```
(s,a)=>/^(.*).*(\n\1.*)*$/.exec(a.filter(e=>e.startsWith(s)).join`
`)[1]||s
```

Explanation: Filters on all matching prefixes, then joins with newlines and matches against a regex that finds the longest common prefix of all lines. If there are no prefixes then the regex returns an empty string in which case we simply return the original string.

Comment: You can replace `e.startsWith(s)` with `e.match("^"+s)` for a byte off Currying will save another

Comment: @ShaunH I can't use `match` with arbitrary printable ASCII.

Comment: Oh right regex and control characters. you can still curry  `(s,a)=>` to `s=>a=>`

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>14</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḣJ$€ċÐff\ṪṪȯ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bijSiTigqzEi8OQZmZc4bmq4bmqyK8&input=&args=WydhcHBseScsJ2FwcGxlJywnYXBwbGUgcGllJywnZWF0J10+J2En) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bijSiTigqzEi8OQZmZc4bmq4bmqyK8Kw6dAMi9Z&input=&args=J2EnLCBbJ2FwcGx5JywnYXBwbGUnLCdhcHBsZSBwaWUnLCdlYXQnXSAsICdhJywgWydhcHBsZSBwaWUnXSAsICdhcHBsZScsIFsnZWF0JywnZGluZSddICwgJ3Byb2dyYW0nLCBbJ3Byb2dyYW1hJywncHJvZ3JhbWInXSAsICcqJWEoJywgWycqJWEoKS1UPicsJyolYSgpLVQ8JywnQERhXm4mJ10gLCAnYScsIFsnYWJzJywnYWJzb2x1dGUnLCdhbnN3ZXInXSAsICdvbmUgdG8nLCBbJ29uZSB0byBvbmUnLCdvbmUgdG8gbWFueSdd).

#### How it works

```
ḣJ$€ċÐff\ṪṪȯ  Main link. Left argument: B. Right argument: A

  $€          Convert the two links to the left into a monadic chain and apply it
              to each string s in B.
 J              Generate the indices of s, i.e., [1, ..., len(s)].
ḣ               Head; for each index i, take the first i characters of s.
              This generates the prefixes of all strings in B.
     Ðf       Filter; keep prefixes for which the link to the left returns 1.
   ċ            Count the number of times A appears in the prefixes of that string.
       f\     Do a cumulative (i.e., keeping all intermediate values) reduce by
              filter, keeping only common prefixes. f/ is a more obvious choice,
              but it errors on an empty array, i.e., when A isn't a prefix of any
              string in B.
         Ṫ    Tail; take the last prefix array (if any) or return 0.
          Ṫ   Tail; take the last common prefix (if any) or return 0.
           ȯ  Logical OR (flat); replace 0 with A, leave strings untouched.
```

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, <s>14</s> 13 bytes

*Thanks to @isaacg for -1 byte*

```
.xe@F/#z._MQz
```

A program that takes the list of strings, and then the string, on STDIN and prints the result.

[Verify all test cases](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.xe%40F%2F%23z._MQz&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%27apply%27%2C%27apple%27%2C%27apple+pie%27%2C%27eat%27%5D%0Aa%0A%5B%27apple+pie%27%5D%0Aa%0A%5B%27eat%27%2C+%27dine%27%5D%0Aapple%0A%5B%27programa%27%2C+%27programb%27%5D%0Aprogram%0A%5B%27%2a%25a%28%29-T%3E%27%2C+%27%2a%25a%28%29-T%3C%27%2C+%27%40Da%5En%26%27%5D%0A%2a%25a%28%0A%5B%27one+to+one%27%2C+%27one+to+many%27%5D%0Aone+to&debug=0&input_size=2)

**How it works**

```
.xe@F/#z._MQz  Program. Inputs: Q, z
        ._MQ   Map prefixes over Q
     /#z       Filter that by count(z)>0, removing the prefixes corresponding to elements
               in Q that do not start with z
   @F          Fold intersection over that. This yields all the common prefixes
  e            Yield the last element of that, giving the longest common prefix, since the
               prefixes are already sorted by length
.x             But if that throws an exception since no elements of Q start with z:
            z  Yield z instead
               Implicitly print
```

Comment: `f}zT` => `/#z`

Answer (score 5):

### PowerShell v3+, 112 bytes

```
param($a,$b)if($c=@($b-like"$a*")){([char[]]$c[0]|%{($i+="$_")}|?{($c-like"$_*").count-eq$c.count})[-1]}else{$a}
```

Takes input as a string `$a` and an array of strings `$b`. Uses the `-like` operator to pull out those elements from `$b` that (case-insensitive) starts with `$a`, explicitly cast those as an array `@(...)` (since the result could be one match as a scalar, in which case indexing later fails), and store that array into `$c`.

That forms the `if` clause. If there's nothing in `$c` (i.e., nothing starts with `$a`, so the array is empty), then output `$a` with the `else`. Otherwise ...

We cast the first element of `$c` as a `char`-array and loop through each element, string-concatenating with the previous `$i` and placing the strings on the pipeline via encapsulating parens. Those are filtered through `|?{...}` (the `Where-Object` clause) to verify that the `.count` of `$c` is `-eq`ual to the `.count` of things in `$c` that are `-like` the substring (i.e., the substring matches everything in $c). Since we're building our substrings in order shortest to longest, we need the last `[-1]` of the resultant strings.

#### Test Cases

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> $tests=@('a',@('apply','apple','apple pie','eat')),@('a',@('apple pie')),@('apple',@('eat','dine')),@('program',@('programa','programb')),@('one to',@('one to one','one to many')),@('*%a(',@('*%a()-T>', '*%a()-T<', '@Da^n&'))

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> $tests|%{""+$_[0]+" ("+($_[1]-join',')+") -> "+(.\implement-tab-completion.ps1 $_[0] $_[1])}
a (apply,apple,apple pie,eat) -> appl
a (apple pie) -> apple pie
apple (eat,dine) -> apple
program (programa,programb) -> program
one to (one to one,one to many) -> one to 
*%a( (*%a()-T>,*%a()-T<,@Da^n&) -> *%a()-T
```

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2, 122 bytes

```
s=input();l=[x for x in input()if x[:len(s)]==s]or[s];i=len(l[0])
while len(l)>1:i-=1;l=set(x[:i]for x in l)
print l.pop()
```

Full program; takes string and list from stdin exactly as given in the examples, except the inputs must be on separate lines.

[Verify all test cases](http://ideone.com/winJs0)

Comment: Why `l.pop()` instead of `l[-1]`?

Comment: @Cyoce Because `l` is usually a `set` at that point, which doesn't allow indexing (being unordered). (Fortunately, both sets and lists support `pop()`.)

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 61 bytes

Includes +2 for `-0p`

Run with the first word followed by the dictionary words on STDIN:

```
tabcompletion.pl
a
apply
apple
apple pie
eat
^D
```

`tabcompletion.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -0p
/^(.+)
((?!\1).*
)*(\1.*).*
((?!\1).*
|\3.*
)*$|
/;$_=$3||$`
```

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 54 bytes

Includes +2 for `-Xp` (can be combined with `-e`) and +3 for `-i` (cannot be combined)

Give dictionary on STDIN and the word after the `-i` option, e.g.:

```
perl -ia -Xpe '/^\Q$^I\E.*?(?{$F[$a{$&}++]=$&})^/}{$_=pop@F||$^I'
apply
apple
apple pie
eat
^D
```

Just the code:

```
/^\Q$^I\E.*?(?{$F[$a{$&}++]=$&})^/}{$_=pop@F||$^I
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 112 bytes

```
lambda n,h:[a.pop()for a in[{s[:-i]for s in h if s.find(n)==0}for i in range(-len(`h`),0)]+[{n}]if len(a)==1][0]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 67 bytes

```haskell
(a:b)?(c:d)|a==c=a:(b?d)
_?_=""
s%l=foldr1(?)$max[s][x|x<-l,x?s==s]
```

The auxiliary function `?` finds the longest common prefix of two strings by recursively taking the first character as long as it's the same for both strings and the strings are non-empty.

The main function `%` first keeps only the strings in the list that start with the given one `s`, checked by the longest common prefix with `s` being `s`. To handle there being no valid competitions, it adds `s` to an empty result via `max`. Then, it finds the longest common prefix of those by folding the binary function `?`.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 75 bytes

```python
import os
lambda s,x:os.path.commonprefix([t for t in x if s<=t<s+'ÿ'])or s
```

*Thanks to @xnor for suggesting the built-in, originally used by  @BetaDecay in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62800/12012).*

For scoring purposes, `ÿ` can be replaced with a DEL byte. Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/5OCJjn).

Answer (score 1):

### D, 88 bytes

```
S f(S)(S p,S[]q){try p=q.filter!(a=>a.startsWith(p)).fold!commonPrefix;catch{}return p;}
```

**Usage:**

```
assert(f("a", ["apply","apple","apple pie","eat"]) ==  "appl");
```

The code simply removes all elements from `q` that don't start with `p`, then computes the largest common initial subsequence of the remaining elements.

The templated parameters save us two repetitions of `string` and one of `auto`.  The exception misuse lets us avoid the temporary variable and conditional that would otherwise be necessary to handle the case where no elements of `q` start with `p`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>107</s> 102 bytes

```python
s,x=input();r='';q=1
for c in zip(*[t for t in x if s<=t<s+'ÿ']):q/=len(set(c));r+=c[0]*q
print r or s
```

For scoring purposes, `ÿ` can be replaced with a DEL byte. Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/HhyJFs).

*Thanks to @xnor for saving 5 bytes!*

Comment: With `os.path.commonprefix` [as Beta Decay found](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62800/20260), you can have it do the work for you.

Comment: Wow, that saves *a lot* of bytes. Are you sure you don't want to post that yourself?

Comment: I wouldn't feel right posting it myself since it's solely Beta Decay's idea combined with your answer.

Comment: For your solution, it looks a bit shorter to iterate `for c in ...` directly and terminate with error after printing like `if len(set(c))>1:print r or s;_`.

Comment: I think that would fail if **x** is a singleton array.

Comment: Oh, I see. It still seems to save bytes to print afterwards, but use a boolean multiplier to the appended character that starts as 1 and becomes 0 when uniqueness is violated.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>167</s> <s>160</s> <s>157</s> 152 bytes

```
<?for($r=preg_grep("$^".preg_quote($s=$_GET[s])."$",$a=$_GET[a]);$r[0]>$s&&preg_grep("$^".preg_quote($t=$s.$r[0][strlen($s)])."$",$a)==$r;)$s=$t;echo$s;
```

I could save 3 more bytes by assigning variables with `preg_grep` and `preg_quote`, but eh.

**breakdown**

```
for(
    // find items in $a that start with $s
    $r=preg_grep("$^".preg_quote($s=$_GET[s])."$",$a=$_GET[a]);
    // while the first match is longer than $s
    $r[0]>$s
    // and appending the next character of the first match
    &&preg_grep("$^".preg_quote($t=$s.$r[0][strlen($s)])."$",$a)
    // does not change the matches
    ==$r
;)
    // keep appending
    $s=$t;
return$s;
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 156 Bytes

with much Help from Titus Thank You

```
<?foreach($_GET[t]as$v)if(strstr($v,$s=$_GET[s])==$v)$r[]=$z=$v;for(;$i++<strlen($z);){$s=substr($z,0,$i);foreach($r as$x)if($x[$i]!=$z[$i])break 2;}echo$s;
```

## PHP, 199 Bytes

32 Bytes saves by Titus with array_unique

```
<?foreach($_GET[t]as$v)if(strstr($v,$s=$_GET[s])==$v)$r[]=$v;for(;$i++<strlen($r[0]);$a=[]){foreach($r as$x)$a[]=substr($x,0,$i);if(count($r)==count($a)&count(array_unique($a))<2)$s=$a[0];}echo$s;
```

I know that the Regex Solution by Titus was shorter till Titus help me to improve my way. Maybe the way I found is interesting for you

Comment: 1) Replace `$z` with `$s` to fix the `apple, [eat,dine]` case.

2) `$l=` is obsolete; You don´t use that variable. (-2)
3) `$i++<$m` is shorter than `++$i<=$m`. (-1)
4) `substr($x,0,$i);` is shorter than `str_split($x,$i)[0]`. (-3)
5) You can put `$r[]=$v` inside the strlen. (-5)

Comment: 6) `<2` is shorter than `==1`. (-1)
7) You could use `strstr` in the first loop: `strstr($v,$s)==$v`. (-3)

Comment: 8) I really like the `count(array_unique())` part. But You can save a whole lot with inverting the last condition and putting the curlys in the inner loop instead of the outer: `foreach($r as$x){if($x[$i]!=$r[0][$i])break 2;$s=substr($x,0,$i);}`. (-33)

Comment: @Titus 1-467 Done 5) Your proposal fill the array without check the condition. That is not which I Would reach.

Comment: Let me rephrase it: 5) You can combine `$r[]=$v;$m=max($m,strlen($v));` to `$m=max($m,strlen($r[]=$v));` and drop the curlys. This doesn´t touch the condition.

Comment: On second thought, you don´t need `$m` at all. All you need is something that is >= the minimum length of the replacements. The new 5) Replace `{$r[]=$v;$m=max($m,strlen($v));}` with `$r[]=$v;}` and `<$m` with `<strlen($r[0])` (-13)

Comment: @Titus All Done and I have found additional 8 Bytes so that our solutions have the same length

Comment: Great! And I just found another golf: 9) `$r[]=$z=$v;` in the first loop and `{$s=substr($z,0,$i);foreach($r as$x)if($x[$i]!=$z[$i])break 2;}` for the second (-3)

Comment: Oh I forgot: You have to add the PHP tag `<?` if you work with a web server. (+2)

Answer (score 1):

### Retina, 60 bytes

```
^(.*)(\n(?!\1).*)*(\n(\1.*)).*(\n((?!\1)|\4).*)*$
$4
s`\n.*
```

The trailing new line is significant. Takes input as the string on a line and then each word on a separate line (but no trailing newline!). Works in a similar way to my JavaScript answer by matching the longest common prefix of all lines that begin with the string on the first line. If it doesn't find one then it simply deletes all the words.

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 119 bytes

```
def f(s:String,a:Seq[Char]*)=a filter(_ startsWith s)reduceOption(_ zip _ takeWhile(t=>t._1==t._2)map(_._1))getOrElse s
```

Ungolfed:

```
def tabComplete(input: String, options: Seq[Char]*) = {
  options.
  filter((x: String) => x.startsWith(input)).
  reduceOption((x: Seq[Char], y: Seq[Char]) =>
    x.zip(y).
    takeWhile((t: (Char, Char)) => t._1 == t._2).
    map((t: (Char, Char)) => t._1)
  ).getOrElse(input)
}
```

Explanation:

```
def g(s:String,a:Seq[Char]*)= //define a method g with a string and a vararg array of strings as parameter
  a filter(_ startsWith s)    //filter the options to contains only elements starting with the input
  reduceOption(               //if the filtered array is nonempty, reduce it: 
    _ zip _                     //zip two elements together
    takeWhile(t=>t._1==t._2)    //take the tuples while they contain the same char
    map(_._1)                   //take the first element from each tuple
  )getOrElse s                //else return the input
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 101 bytes

*Based on [Nail's awesome regexp](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94420/80745)*.

```powershell
if($args-join'
'-cmatch'^(.*)(\n(?!\1).*)*(\n(\1.*)).*(\n((?!\1)|\4).*)*$'){$Matches.4}else{$args[0]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLLboMwELzzFW7kZG0EUSPlVPXBodfeeitN5SSbhAoMwkRtRPh2umAe6eNQH@yZnZnVYpylH5ibA8ZxzXfsjpV1tBNc5Xvjv6eRBgf8TaKKzQFWYu5KEWrxcBUuJGG3IeGCELEGW@UcLluVgyz5UxNFM19WGBss28Yv169VXTlOIBxGyxOgsiwG1i0PFIyQlBN4gAoswf5kWYRWkJdtbP2vNlb5bv7hsDlUBTXeRvrCneXpPlcJdO6BDrCZr4PrMeZOlZD@cx9rKIyQlHsY4C3B4FGt9OxiyOFWfn3R2kC7p/GxaC9FG/qT/4ra4GhNNbIiZf2UlsIIGR0wkETpE2UlO7MpK9seHD8z3BS49RhX9Ij4my3naI5xQYUZva1AtcUJF13dj/QQlDe9e@JU9Rc)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ʒIÅ?}€ηøʒË}‚˜θ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//1CTPw632tY@a1pzbfnjHqUmHu2sfNcw6Pefcjv//o5USCwpyKpV0wHQqjFYoyASxUxNLlGK5EgE) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WeWHv4Qku9qFKCol5KQpK9pXndrjYKyk8apsE5Pw/NSnicKt97aOmNee2H95xatLh7tpHDbNOzzm347/O/@hopUQlHQUgWVCQU6mkA6ZTYbRCQSaInZpYohQbC1alpBONJAUVhGiJBqvTUUrJzIPJFBTlpxcl5oLkoEygATBmElSRlmqiBkgFiNbUDbEDqoAybYBMB5fEuDw1FOuTikHuSyrOzyktATs1r7g8tQhFCVhBMlQoPy9VoSQfJA5hKQApoAIoJzcxrxKqMBmkJjk/JbUCKJ2UAzIFxEvPz0kDqogFAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ʒ   }           # Filter the (implicit) input-list
 IÅ?            #  Does it start with the (second) input-string
                #   i.e. ["codex","bla","codegolf"] and "c" → ["codex","codegolf"]
     €η         # Then take the prefixes of every remaining string
                #  → [["c","co","cod","code","codex"],
                #     ["c","co","cod","code","codeg","codego","codegol","codegolf"]]
       ø        # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
                #  → [["c","c"],["co","co"],["cod","cod"],["code","code"],["codex","codeg"]]
        ʒ }     # Filter:
         Ë      #  Only keep sublists which only contain the same substrings
                #   → [["c","c"],["co","co"],["cod","cod"],["code","code"]]
           ‚    # Pair it with the (second implicit) input
                #  → ["c",["c","c"],["co","co"],["cod","cod"],["code","code"]]
                # (workaround if nothing in the input-list starts with the input-string)
            ˜   # Flatten this list
                #  → ["c","c","c","co","co","cod","cod","code","code"]
             θ  # And only leave the last item (which is output implicitly as result)
                #  → "code"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 12 bytes

```
e…¦&⊢…Ė⁇_+ₔ)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/P/VRw7JDy9QedS0CMo5Me9TYHq/9qGmK5v//0Y8a5iQWFOQAVcyFMiuBzFiuAgA)

Takes input as B, then A.

```
e		| eval B as list of strings
 …¦		| take prefixes of each string
   &⊢		| reduce by set intersection
     …		| take list prefixes of each.
      Ė⁇	| Keep only those with A as an element
	_	| flatten
	 +ₔ	| add A to the beginning of the list
	   )	| take the last element
```